# how to Subscribe to EventEmitter retrieved from NgRx Store (with Store-Freez) (ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible)

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6

I'm trying to store (in NgRx Store) an Object that has an EventEmitter,

after retriving it from the Store and subscribing to it I got this message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

**if I disable Store-Freeze everthing works perfectly**. there is any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any example code?

An erro accours when (see: [github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze#readme](http://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze#readme)):
- Recursively freezes the current state, the dispatched action payload if provided and the new state.
- When mutation occurs, an exception will be thrown.

You wrote, you are trying to store an EventEmitter! Do you maybe mean an `event instance` which is created from `EventEmitter`

Is only a guess: maybe the event itself is mutating after your stored it and thats why you are get an error because `ngrx-store-freeze` is enabled! Thats good because you can see in development mode when something went wrong. NgRx or Redux followed the principle you get always `immutable data` and while developing `ngrx-store-freeze` informs you.

Comment: Hi there thanks for answering,

with "store an EventEmitter!" I ment to store an Angular EventEmitter, or better an Object that has an EventEmitter in it eg:

`export interface Example {
    id?: string;
    theClass?: string;
    click?: EventEmitter<{}>;
    timeoutEnd?: EventEmitter<{}>;
}`

Comment: This is also true if I pass it from an Effect to another Effect